# Create an array where the elements are determined by non null values in a row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following sheet to track participation in events...

[image]

... that continues for hundreds of columns and rows. A blank cell indicates that person did not participate in that event. I can not change the layout of this sheet.

For each name I need to create an array of Event IDs for the events they have participated in, which would look like this:

[image]

Columns would be fine too.

I am already able to generate this array using (pseudo-formula) `QUERY(TRANSPOSE(range), "SELECT (Event ID column) WHERE (user column) IS NOT NULL", 0)`, however I'm looking for a solution that does not need to TRANSPOSE the sheet, either in memory or in a separate 'helper' sheet.

Comment: What's the reason for not using `TRANSPOSE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try on below formula.

```
=FILTER($C$1:$G$1,FILTER($C$3:$G$6,$A$3:$A$6=A8)<>"")
```

[image]